# Oracle SQL checking for overlapped dates using a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sql-insert

I have the table named EPOCA with this schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EPOCA
(
    ID       INT
        CONSTRAINT PK_EPOCA PRIMARY KEY,
    NOME     VARCHAR(250),
    DATE_INITIAL DATE
        CONSTRAINT NN_EPOCA_DATA_INI NOT NULL,
    DATE_END DATE,
    CONSTRAINT CK_EPOCA_DATAS CHECK (DATE_INITIAL < DATE_END)
);
```

And even though I already check if the initial date is smaller then the end date, I need to check that when I insert a new EPOCA the dates I insert will not overlap with any of the present dates.

I developed this trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRGEPOCASNAOSOBREPOSTAS
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON EPOCA
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    FLAG_DATE NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FLAG_DATE := 0;

    IF INSERTING THEN
        SELECT E.ID INTO FLAG_DATE FROM EPOCA E WHERE E.DATE_INITIAL < :NEW.DATE_INITIAL AND E.DATE_END > :NEW.DATE_END;
        IF FLAG_DATE <> 0 THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-2098, 'INSERT FAILED BECAUSE SELECTED DATES OVERLAP EXISTENT ONES');
        END IF;
    ELSIF UPDATING THEN
        SELECT E.ID INTO FLAG_DATE FROM EPOCA E WHERE E.DATE_INITIAL < :NEW.DATE_INITIAL AND E.DATA_END > :NEW.DATA_END;
        IF FLAG_DATE <> 0 THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-2099, 'UPDATE FAILED BECAUSE SELECTED DATES OVERLAP EXISTENT ONES');
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

The error I am getting when inserting is because no data was found on line 7 of the trigger and when I am updating the table the error is because the table is in mutation and the trigger cannot read the table, which makes sense but I don't know how to solve it.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan done it, thanks and sorry!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use the `count` aggregate function in your `select` query at both places as it always returns tge count evenif it is zero as follows:

```
...
...
SELECT count(*) INTO FLAG_DATE FROM EPOCA E WHERE E.DATA_INI < :NEW.DATA_INI AND E.DATA_FIM > :NEW.DATA_FIM;
IF FLAG_DATE <> 0 THEN
...
...
```

Comment: I changed my current script using OLD and NEW annotations and ditched the SELECT that i was initially using, thank you very much anyway!

Comment: In a ROW LEVEL TRIGGER this will raise an `ORA-04091: table EPOCA  is mutating, trigger/function may not see it`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `SELECT` statement, but convert your code to the one such as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRGEPOCASNAOSOBREPOSTAS
BEFORE UPDATE
ON EPOCA
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    FLAG_DATE NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FLAG_DATE := 0;

    IF UPDATING THEN
        IF :OLD.DATE_INITIAL < :NEW.DATE_INITIAL AND :OLD.DATE_END > :NEW.DATE_END THEN
           FLAG_DATE := :OLD.ID;
        END IF;
        IF FLAG_DATE <> 0 THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-2099, 'UPDATE FAILED BECAUSE SELECTED DATES OVERLAP EXISTENT ONES');
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

*where no need to use `INSERTING` case( the trigger should be `BEFORE UPDATE` only ). Since the desired condition is already provided as the check constraint within the table's definition.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will now eddit my current code so you can see what I've made, because now I can verify overlaped dates when UPDATING but I can insert overlaped dates and my trigger doesn't catch it, still adds the data to the table.

Comment: Using `:OLD` for `INSERT` statements is useless.

Comment: `IF :NEW.DATE_INITIAL > :NEW.DATE_END` is also useless. This is already prevented by `CONSTRAINT CK_EPOCA_DATAS CHECK (DATE_INITIAL < DATE_END)`