# Why is this trigger allowing to insert but denying the update

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

This trigger should not allow to insert or update values within the same date of the values that are already on a table, but allows the insert and denies the update

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trgepocasnaosobrepostas BEFORE
        UPDATE OR INSERT ON epoca
        FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
        ex_data_sobreposta EXCEPTION;
    BEGIN
        IF ( ( :new.data_ini BETWEEN :old.data_ini AND :old.data_fim ) OR ( :new.data_fim BETWEEN :old.data_ini AND  :old.data_fim ) ) THEN
            RAISE ex_data_sobreposta;
        END IF;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN ex_data_sobreposta THEN
            raise_application_error(-20000, 'datas sobrepõem épocas');
    END trgepocasnaosobrepostas;
    /
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65278704/1509264).

Comment: Is the update scenario even correct? From your explanation it sounds as if you’re expecting it to look at other rows that exist in the table - you’re not doing that, you’re just comparing it to the values that the modified row had. Looking at the other rows in your table is trickier than it sounds - google the mutating table error. You may need to do something clever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:old` and `:new` relate to the single row that is being updated/instered and there are no `:old` values on an `INSERT` (since the row did not exist previously) so trying to do:

```sql
:new.data_ini BETWEEN :old.data_ini AND :old.data_fim
```

Is equivalent to:

```sql
:new.data_ini BETWEEN NULL AND NULL
```

Which will always be false.

If you want to check the entire table for overlaps then you want a solution like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65279658/1509264).